# Is $ \ln \delta \int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz \sim \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r) f(\delta^{1/r}) $?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, solution-verification, mobius-inversion

### Background

I think I can show something interesting:

$$  \ln \delta  \int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz \sim \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r) f(\delta^{1/r}) $$

where $\delta \to 0$ and $\int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz$ converges. However, there is something that worries me. Let $\delta \to \delta^{1/k}$:

$$  \frac{1}{k}\ln \delta  \int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz \sim 
 \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r)f(\delta^{1/(kr)})  $$

Summing both sides $k=1$ to $\infty$:

$$  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\ln \delta  \int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz  \sim f(\delta) $$

Obviously the L.H.S goes to $\infty$ where as the R.H.S is finite. Can someone spot the error (in the contradiction/proof)?

### Proof

Consider:

$$ f(u) +f(u^{1/2}) + f(u^{1/3}) + \dots = g(u) $$

Now consider:

$$ I = \int_0^\infty f(e^{-1/x}) dx $$

Writing using asymptotics and using Riemann limit of a sum with $\epsilon \to 0$:

$$ I \sim (f(e^{-1/\epsilon}) + f(e^{-1/ 2 \epsilon}) + f(e^{-1/3 \epsilon}) + \dots )\epsilon$$

Now using $\epsilon = \frac{-1}{\ln \delta} \to 0$. Hence:

$$ -( \ln \delta )I \sim f(\delta) +f(\delta^{1/2}) + f(\delta^{1/3}) + \dots$$

Substituting $g(\delta)$ and $I$:
$$ -( \ln \delta ) \int_0^\infty f(e^{-1/x}) dx \sim g(\delta)$$

Using mobius inversion:

$$ -( \ln \delta ) \int_0^\infty f(e^{-1/x}) dx \sim \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r)f(\delta^{1/r}) $$

Now, let $z=\exp(-1/x)$ and $dx = \frac{dz}{-z (\ln z)^2}$. Hence,

$$  \ln \delta  \int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz \sim \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r)f(\delta^{1/r}) $$

where $\delta \to 0$ and $\int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz$ converges.

Comment: Is it possible there exists no $f$ such that $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r) f(\delta^{1/r}) $ and $\int_0^1 \frac{f(z)}{z(\ln z)^2} dz$ is finite simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write
$$
-(\log \delta) I\sim \left(f(\delta)+f(\delta^{1/2})+f(\delta^{1/3})+\ldots\right).
$$
Then
$$
-(\log\delta)\int^{\infty}_{0}f(e^{-1/x})dx\sim g(\delta)
$$
which is right. But then you say: Using Moebius inversion
$$
-(\log\delta)\int^{\infty}_{0}f(e^{-1/x})dx\sim \sum^{\infty}_{r=1}\mu(r)f(\delta^{1/r}).
$$
This is not true since it is again
$$
-(\log\delta)\int^{\infty}_{0}f(e^{-1/x})dx\sim \sum^{\infty}_{r=1}f(\delta^{1/r})
$$
and you perform no inversion. The right formula is
$$
\int^{1}_{0}\frac{f(t)}{t\log^2 t}dt=-\frac{1}{\log \delta}\sum^{\infty}_{r=1}f(\delta^{1/r})+o_{\delta}(1)\textrm{, }\delta\rightarrow 0^{+}
$$
for $\frac{f(t)}{t\log^2 t}$ continuous and bounded in $[0,1]$. Say $f(t)=\sin^2(\pi t)$, $f(t)=(t(t-1))^2$. In general holds the next

**Theorem** (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence)). If $s_n$, $n\geq 1$ is uniformly distributed in $[a,b]$, $a<b$ and $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded in $[a,b]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{j=1}g\left(s_j\right)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int^{b}_{a}g(t)dt.
$$

And, also
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}f(e^{-1/t})dt=\int^{b}_{0}f(e^{-1/t})dt+\int^{\infty}_{b}f(e^{-1/t})dt\sim\epsilon\sum^{N}_{k=1}f(e^{-1/k\epsilon})+\int^{\infty}_{b}f(e^{-1/t})dt,
$$
where $\epsilon=b/N$